# `gem update` only for new versions

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I run `gem update`, every installed gem is processed, which is generally a waste of time.

How do I update a gem only if a new version is available?

Comment: You can check by `bundle outdated` as It lists installed gems with newer versions available then you can update single gem `bundle update gem_name`

Comment: @ts I'm not asking about `bundle`... rather `gem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exist next option for gem:

```
-​-conservative - Don’t attempt to upgrade gems already meeting version requirement
```

Link to documentation: https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-update